# Cisco WLC show time only in one line?

Tags: cisco-wlc

The following `show time` output is taken from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/8-3/command-reference/b-cr83/show_commands_r_to_z.html#wp2143390613

Since I can't find `show clock` in WLC, I was wondering if there is away to just get the time only from `show time`. Pipe, include and grep doesn't work on WLC.

There is too much information given on `show time`. All I need is date, time, and timezone only.

```
> show time
Time............................................. Wed Apr 13 09:29:15 2011
Timezone delta................................... 0:0
Timezone location........................ (GMT +5:30) Colombo, New Delhi, Chennai, Kolkata
NTP Servers
    NTP Polling Interval.........................     3600
     Index     NTP Key Index     NTP Server      NTP Msg Auth Status
    -------  ---------------------------------------------------------------
       1              0           9.2.60.60       AUTH DISABLED
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is too much information? It's the only way to get time information on a Cisco WLC CLI.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if the time on a WLC is _way_ off (years) APs won’t associate to the controller.  Hopefully that 2011 output is from documentation.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command. 
WLC version should be after v7.5

`grep include 'Time\.' "show time"`

I didn't have the device.
I'm not unclear what kind of regex option can be used.
Check the following filter example.

`grep include '20[0-9][0-9]' "show time"`
`grep include 'Time' "show time"`
`grep include 'Timezone delta' "show time"`
`grep exclude 'Timezone' "show time"`